# Things that are similar to C# event handlers in PHP

Tags: c#, php

I'd like to know what is the thing similar to C# event handlers in PHP.

e.g. When a button is clicked, every functions attached to the event on click are called.

Comment: No.You have to use client side languages like javascript or jquery for that..

Comment: Do you mean like `Asp.net`?

Comment: then, how do we do that in javascript?

Comment: you could use $_get and $_post which you could compare to event handling, but isn't realy.

Comment: @User016 you're probably right, but jQuery is not a language but a javascript helper.

Comment: I have posted an ansewr which contains some reeference links.Check that.. Because its too hard to explain it as an answer here...

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing like this out of the box in PHP, but there is a framework called [PRADO](http://www.pradosoft.com/) which tries to bring event-driven development to PHP.

Comment: I would suggest to add a sample of code about an event implementation, and a call, so we can better see what PRADO offers as solution.

Comment: @Dereckson: I'm not experienced in PRADO so I don't feel up to providing a reasonable code example. I added my answer because I think this is what OP asked for and no other answer suggested it. If you know PRADO, feel free to add an answer with some code samples. I will gladly upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you make use of isset to see if a button was clicked.  For instance:

```
if (isset($_POST['button'])) {
    $Variable = $_POST['button'];
}
```

The button then looks like this in HTML

```
<input type="submit" name="button" value="ButtonName">
```

Comment: And that is not an event handling method.Its about form submittin..

Answer (score 0):

In web development this is managed by client side. So it's not PHP which check user action, it's javascript and HTML.

you can bind HTML to PHP action with HTML tags `<form>` and `<a>`.

For pure JavaScript events, you can start to check this [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event)

There is lots of JS libraries built to ease event management like [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 0):

You can either use Javascript events triggered by the html tag onclick. Have a look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) if you choose to use that way.

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

You can alo use jQuery to trigger various events for example. Have a look at [this](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
If you choose to use this solution you can also trigger various ajax based functions.

```
$('button').click()
```

But if you want to trigger serversided events you need to add a form and submit the values to a php script for example:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['someVal'])){
echo "Hello";
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="someVal" />
    <input type="submit" value="send" />
    </form>
```